# What is a good simile or metaphor for being swallowed in by a crowd, or being surrounded by people?

Tags: metaphors, simile

What is a good simile or metaphor for being swallowed in by a crowd, or being surrounded by people? I am writing a narrative, and in my case I said "I got swallowed in by the crowd." Is there any good simile or metaphor that will complete my sentence? I would prefer a simile if there is any good ones, but a metaphor would also be great.

Comment: *"I got swallowed in by the crowd."* is not what you want. *“to swallow in”* is not idiomatic. If you want a simile: *I got swallowed **by** the crowd like a … swallows a …* However, you **must** now give some context to explain what sensation or impression you wish to imply.

Comment: The use of 'swallowed' is already metaphor.  You could be engulfed in a tide of people.

Comment: I think we have both metaphor and simile here: *The crowd swallowed me like a boa constrictor dining on a squirrel.*

Comment: I would say 'swallowed **up**'.

Answer (score 1):

You were engulfed by the crowd. The analogy is with the flow of water covering or surrounding things.

> engulf: transitive verb
>
> 1 : to flow over and enclose : OVERWHELM
> the mounting seas threatened to engulf the island
>
> 2 : to take in (food) by or as if by flowing over and enclosing
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engulf)

Comment: thank you for the better words for the sentence, that really helped, but do you have any similes, or metaphors for after that sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The crowd *drown out* his cries for help.

> "drown out" transitive verb
> : to drive (a person or an animal) from home by flooding
> : force (as a mine) to shut down by inundation

[merriam-webster's defintion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drown%20out)
[free dictionary specifies more of the metaphoric qualities](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drown+out)

Comment: Thanks for the great metaphor!

Comment: Could you give a definition and provide a link to that definition?

Comment: @fev updated response with definition and link.